# Are a Civ's Unique Buildings transformed when conquered?

Tags: civilization-5

Assume for a moment that I am playing the Ethiopians, currently at war with the Egyptian empire.

Egypt has a unique building, the Burial Tomb, that replaces the Temple. My spies have already told me that the Egyptian city of "InvadeMe" contains one of these, as well as a generic Monument building.

If my forces conquer the city, what happens?

- Does the Burial Tomb get converted into a Temple? (Since Ethiopians can only build Temples)
- Does the Monument get converted into a Stele? (Since Ethiopians can't build generic monuments)

(I just used Ethiopians off the top of my head, this question is not G&K specific)

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think they might just be destroyed, because every time I conquer a city there are barely, if any, buildings left.

Comment: When you conquer a city half the buildings and population are destroyed.  I think the original building built stays, so the Ethiopians would have Egyptian burial tombs as said in your example, but i don't have time to confirm this now so i wont put it as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: They convert to the correct building of the conquering Civilization, if they survive at all.

I fired up Civ V, with the [In-Game Editor](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=77002777) mod running. It doesn't edit any mechanics, so it's great for testing out things like this. No other mods were running.

I played as Assyria, against Egypt. I would have involved Ethiopia, as per your example, but my experience suggests that cultural buildings never survive, so Steles/Monuments wouldn't work either way. I gave Egypt a second City, with the techs needed, and added a Library, Shrine, and Burial Tomb.

[image: Memphis, with both a Burial Tomb and a Library.]

Then, I declared war, gave myself a Giant Death Robot in the area, and took the city. Once under my control, Memphis had a Royal Library and Temple instead.

[image: Memphis, with a Temple and a Royal Library.]